# Adding second scatter on the 3rd row in subplots

Tags: python, plotly

My code renders:
One the first row - table. On the second row - 2 bar charts. That's fine. The 3rd thing I am trying to display is a bar chart, combined from the 2 bar charts from the second row. I am doing it with `fig.add_traces(...)` and merging the 2 bar charts. But it appears under the table in the pdf. I tried with `specs` but nothing. Also tried to add `row=3, col=1` to the `fig.add_traces` but it doesn't allow me. My code:

```
from plotly import graph_objs as go
import numpy as np
import os
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

fig = make_subplots(rows=3, cols=2)

website_fig = go.Bar(
        x=[
            "01/09/2019 - 07/09/2019",
            "08/09/2019 - 14/09/2019", 
            "15/09/2019 - 21/09/2019",
            "22/09/2019 - 28/09/2019"
            ],
        y=[15, 25, 35, 32],
        name= "Website statistic"
    )

linkedin_fig = go.Bar(
        x=[
            "01/09/2019 - 07/09/2019",
            "08/09/2019 - 14/09/2019", 
            "15/09/2019 - 21/09/2019",
            "22/09/2019 - 28/09/2019"
            ],
        y=[153, 102, 187, 200],
        name= "LinkedIn statistic"
    )

# Chart product views
fig.add_trace(  
    website_fig,
    row=2,
    col=1
)

# Chart product views LinkedIn
fig.add_trace(  
    linkedin_fig,
    row=2,
    col=2
)

wesbite_views = [15, 25, 35, 32]
wesbite_views.append(sum(wesbite_views))
linkedin_views = [153, 102, 187, 200]
linkedin_views.append(sum(linkedin_views))
total_views  = [x + y for x, y in zip(wesbite_views, linkedin_views)]

# Product views table
fig.add_trace(
    go.Table(
        header=dict(values=["Period", "Website views", "LinkedIn views", "Total views"]),
        cells=dict(values=[
            [
                "01/09/2019 - 07/09/2019",
                "08/09/2019 - 14/09/2019", 
                "15/09/2019 - 21/09/2019",
                "22/09/2019 - 28/09/2019",
                "01/09/2019 - 28/09/2019",
            ],
            wesbite_views,
            linkedin_views,
            total_views
        ])
    )
)

fig.add_traces([
        go.Scatter(
            x=[
                "01/09/2019 - 07/09/2019",
                "08/09/2019 - 14/09/2019", 
                "15/09/2019 - 21/09/2019",
                "22/09/2019 - 28/09/2019"
                ],
            y=[15, 25, 35, 32],
        ),
        go.Scatter(
            x=[
                "01/09/2019 - 07/09/2019",
                "08/09/2019 - 14/09/2019", 
                "15/09/2019 - 21/09/2019",
                "22/09/2019 - 28/09/2019"
                ],
            y=[153, 102, 187, 200],
        ),
    ]
)

if not os.path.exists("files"):
    os.mkdir("files")

fig.update_yaxes(title_text="Product views", range=[0, 40], row=2, col=1)
fig.update_layout(height=700, width=1000, title_text="<b>Library Shelving</b> statistic")
fig.write_image("files/statistic.pdf")
```

Comment: What does “it doesn’t allow me” mean in this context? Is there an error message? Can you share it with us?

Comment: This code could probably be reduced down to give a shorter [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I run `add_traces` with `row` and `col` I get

```
TypeError: add_traces() got an unexpected keyword argument 'row'
```

Looking at [these examples of subplots](https://plot.ly/python/subplots/), it looks like the arguments should be `rows` and `cols`:

```py
fig.add_traces([
        go.Scatter(
            x=[
                "01/09/2019 - 07/09/2019",
                "08/09/2019 - 14/09/2019",
                "15/09/2019 - 21/09/2019",
                "22/09/2019 - 28/09/2019"
                ],
            y=[15, 25, 35, 32],
        ),
        go.Scatter(
            x=[
                "01/09/2019 - 07/09/2019",
                "08/09/2019 - 14/09/2019",
                "15/09/2019 - 21/09/2019",
                "22/09/2019 - 28/09/2019"
                ],
            y=[153, 102, 187, 200],
        ),
    ],
    rows=[3, 3], cols=[1, 1]
)
```

I've also changed the original call to `make_subplots` to

```py
fig = make_subplots(rows=3, cols=2, specs=[
    [{"colspan": 2}, None], [{}, {}], [{"colspan":2}, None]])
```

I've not changed anything else in your code (these are scatter plots instead of line plots)